# Iterating over map of list and inserting values to another Map which contains a customized list of previous list values. Is it possible?

Tags: java, list, filter, java-8, java-stream

```
public class IterateMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("========List of Objects=========");
        Employee emp;

        Map<String,Employee> anotherHashMap = new HashMap<String,Employee>();
        ArrayList<Employee> elist = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        elist.add(new Employee(1, "John","Pillay", 26));
        elist.add(new Employee(2, "Richard","Santos", 25));
        elist.add(new Employee(3, "Deep","Singh", 19));
        elist.add(new Employee(4, "Sandeep","Narwal", 20));
        elist.add(new Employee(5, "Benny","Gaucho", 30));

        for(int i = 0; i < elist.size(); i++){
            emp = elist.get(i);
            anotherHashMap.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), emp);
        }
        System.out.println("================================");
        System.out.println(anotherHashMap);
        System.out.println("================================");

        Map<String, Employee> resultMap = anotherHashMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
                         Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,  e -> new 
                        Employee(e.getValue().getFirstName(),e.getValue().getAge())));
        System.out.println(resultMap);

    }
}
```

---

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {

    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;

    public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Employee()
    {
    }
    public Employee(String name, int age)
    {
        this.age= age;
        this.firstName = name;
    }
    //Getter and setter
}
```

---

Output:

================================

> {cf135244-6d17-471f-8b3a-fd9e0a4e89c2=Employee [id=0, firstName=Benny,
>   lastName=null, age=30], 980a7fea-0616-46d3-8a57-88d66864c67f=Employee
>   [id=0, firstName=Richard, lastName=null, age=25],
>   ae754c99-b998-4c54-9594-59f7268d9a32=Employee [id=0, firstName=John,
>   lastName=null, age=26], f4ccc96f-06d7-4b72-98ca-94ae60eba703=Employee
>   [id=0, firstName=Sandeep, lastName=null, age=20],
>   ce4a50d2-34cf-404c-87e4-435c51764a6f=Employee [id=0, firstName=Deep,
>   lastName=null, age=19]}

---

So in the following output, I want that the attributes present in the list of the resultMap should not contain "lastName=null" & "id=0" attributes, the list of values should be customized to "firstName", "age" . I'm not taking another object to put the values. Is it possible to do so in java-8?

Comment: you mean, it should not print the attributes `"lastName=null"` and `"id=0"` or they should  have some other value?

Comment: Yes, naman. What I meant over there is, it should not print those attributes in the list of the resultMap.

Comment: you can then override the `toString` method for your class or choose to invoke another method with custom code to print the way you want.

Comment: @Naman If I do that then the definition of the object changes. I have created a  new model class for this with "firstName" & "age".  Well I thought there might be some Java-8 expression that will remove those attributes from the resultMap.

Comment: If you've created a new model class, you should map the new object to that and not the existing `Employee` class and that would solve for what you're looking then.